# Locus of centres of circles that touch two intersecting circles

Tags: geometry

let C1, C2 be two circles that intersect each other so we get two Points P1, P2 that lie on both circles.

Now we construct a circle $C_i$ with center $M_i$ so that this circle tangents C1 and C2 from inside.
How can I mathematically find the locus of all the $M_i$ for those circles?

I thought about something like:

the distance from every $M_i$ to the Point where $C_i$ touches C1 has the same length as the distance from $M_i$ to the Point where the same $C_i$ touches C2...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

... Thus the difference of the distances to the circles' centers is constant. The locus is therefore part of a hyperbola having the centers of the circles as focii. In fact, it is subarcs of a branch on this hyperbola.

Of course, points $P_i$ are points of these subarcs.

Comment: Thank you! In this case I can calculate the distance $M_1M_i = r_1 - r_i$ (for example). However, how do I know that the centers of $M_1$ and all $M_i$ are on a line so the ratios can be added?